# How Can I Tee All Apache Logs To Console

Tags: apache-2.4, logging

I want to run apache so that all log messages show up on the console (or at least STDERR and/or STDOUT) because something is going wrong that isn't being logged in any file.

I'm currently sifting through an `strace service apache2 start` but that's a nuclear flyswatter approach to something that should be straight forward.

How can I do it?

The situation in more detail:

Apache responds with a 403 but even after an `updatedb` doing a `locate error.log` or `locate error_log` shows there are no updates to any log files for any virtual host. Nor is there any update to `/var/log/apache2/suexec.log`.

`# apachectl -V
AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:222
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Server built:   Feb 24 2017 18:40:28
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:37
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.1, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Compiled using: APR 1.5.1, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     event
  threaded:     yes (fixed thread count)
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"`

Comment: Maybe try running apache with `-DFOREGROUND -e debug'?

Answer (score 1):

Apache httpd allows you to "pipe" your logs to any other program standard input.

```
CustomLog "| programtoreceivestandardinput parameters bla bla bla" common
ErrorLog "| programtoreceivestandardinput parameters"
```

Most httpd docker images also point to fd files like:

```
CustomLog /proc/self/fd/1 common
```